# Google Script is slow. Using arrays. Anything else I'm missing?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to add students to Google Classrooms ('Courses') from a Google Sheet with code below (function AddStudents).

It's very slow and, if I do too many, it exceeds allowed execution time. Is there anything that I can do to speed it up?

```
function AddStudent(argStudent, argCourseCode) {
  Classroom.Courses.Students.create({
    userId: argStudent,
  }, argCourseCode);
}


function AddStudents() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  
  var shtStudents = ss.getSheetByName('Students');

  var rngStudentCourses = shtStudents.getRange(2,6,645,2);
  var arrStudentCourses = rngStudentCourses.getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < arrStudentCourses.length; i++) {
    AddStudent(arrStudentCourses[i][0], arrStudentCourses[i][1]);
  }
}
```

Comment: the `Classroom.Courses.Students.create` is most likely what is slowing it down as the rest of the code seems as efficient as it can be. If it is this https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.students/create, then maybe there is a way to make an POST request asynchronously (without waiting for result)